# How to define a route that doesn't require an action in the URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Defined a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SearchRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", 
                action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, SearchViewModel model)
```

1. I browse to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Search and my Index action is
   hit on my SearchController, good.
2. I browse to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Search/1 and I get a 404 error.
3. I browse to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Search/Index/1, OK.

I'd rather work with 2 above and not have to type in `/Index/1`.  How?

Comment: can you show index method ?

Comment: The routing system can't tell the difference between an ID and an action name.

Comment: yo what is the SearchViewModel doing there? your search method better be HttpPost

Comment: @SLaks - You can have an action name of "1"?

Comment: @O.O: Yes.  (using the `[ActionName]` attribute)  And even had that not been possible, the routing engine wouldn't know that; as far as the routing engine is concerned, `action` is an arbitrary parameter that can have any value.

Comment: See also http://blog.slaks.net/2011/09/using-default-controller-in-aspnet-mvc.html/, although it's not quite your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SearchRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It will only ever target the `Index` action but it sounds like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is priority in routing, ie: which route you define first matters. Try following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "SearchRoute",
                url: "Search/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Search", 
                action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultRoute",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: This will break `/Search/OtherActionName`